# get app startup path in wcf

Tags: c#, wcf, app-startup

In vs2008 (C#):

I have :

1. a main project (windows app)
2. WCF Library
3. WCF Host
4. WCF Client (Windows app)

For testing my service with created client, I call my client form in my main proj and after getting the input requirement of service by this form, I start making response of service by calling my service contract method .

In this service I need to create a proper connection string with received parameter for request and I need my application startup path (`D:\myProj.dll`) to get access to an exe file. Unfortunately after using different kinds of codes that return this path, exactly at point of calling my service, I get another paths I don't need (`myproj`, `bin\debug` or `c:\programfiles\visual studio9\common7\IDE`)

Can you help me ?

For additional info I have to say that I added this path by a command to post-build event of my service library and client.

Please help me to get access to this path (startup path of my project -> `D:\myProj.dll`)

Thank you in advance

Comment: So you want to get the *client's* startup path in the *service* implementation - correct? That won't work - not EVER. Client and service **only** share a transport wire (a network) and a **service contract** - nothing else. The service **CANNOT** "reach back" to the client to get something. The only thing you could do is have a parameter on your service call which your **caller** fills with its startup path before making the call to the service.

Comment: agreed, based on your question it's unclear whose path you're trying to get.  Additionally, the execution context matters - if you run from within VS your path will be different than if you launch from the shell, or are running from within IIS or a WCF host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa457089.aspx)

```
path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(
          System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
```

to get the path of a DLL your code is using:

```
string fullPath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(MyClass)).Location;
```

Comment: this statement returns bin/debug which is not where my application is running from.actually my application is running from d:myProj.dll . how can I get running path of my host application (my host is a windows service , if it helps!)?

Comment: are you running this from within the VS IDE?

Comment: no I'm just running from myproj.dll ! and I wanna exactly this path.

Comment: Look at my edit above to see how to get the path to a specific dll used by a program.